# How to pass the Directory path as command line for the process?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

iam using regasm.exe to generate tlb file and register the assembly programatically.But the path of tlb in .NET root directory itself. so do like this

buffer contains c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\framework\v2.0.57\RegAsm.exe

```
if(!CreateProcessW(buffer,L" C:\\Program Files\\Test\\Test.dll  /codebase /tlb /silent" ,NULL, NULL,FALSE, 0,NULL,NULL,(LPSTARTUPINFOW)&si,&pi ) )
```

But i think  it wont take full path since there is a blank b/w Program and Files.as expected the when i run the command it also shows unable to locate input assembly c:\program.

normally at command prompt we can give as

RegAsm.exe **"c:\program files\Test\test.dll" /codebase /tlb** 
this bold characters i have to pass as command line but it have Double quptes with in double quotes. so i was strucked.

How can i fix it

Comment: Not relevant to this question, but don't cast the &si, instead declare STARTUPINFOW si;

Comment: HI sahrptooth

I am getting the path of C:\Program Files\Test\ using our existing code as string now i am appending the remaining \test.dll" /codebase /tlb now make it as simply

string asemblypath= obj.installationPath()+"\\test.dll /codebase /tlb"
and now i have to pass this as commandline i just pass it as
CreateProcessW(buffer,assemblypath,xxxxxxxx);
but i got the error cannot convert string to LPWSTR

How can i convert string to LPWSTR ...can u helpme in this regard...

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the path in quotes *within* the string, which you can do by escaping the quote character by preceding it with a backslash. So, your 2nd parameter to CreateProcessW would be:

```
L"\"C:\Program Files\Test\Test.dll\" /codebase /tlb /silent"
```

This would give you the command line with quotes that you would use at the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Just see the documentation for the CreateProcess Function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx

It says:

> lpCommandLine [in, out, optional]  The
>   Unicode version of this function,
>   CreateProcessW, can modify the
>   contents of this string. Therefore,
>   this parameter cannot be a pointer to
>   read-only memory (such as a const
>   variable or a literal string). If this
>   parameter is a constant string, the
>   function may cause an access
>   violation.

It has an example where one specifies an executable in "Program Files" Directory. .
I am not that good in C++. Else would have given an example.