# How to enclose the path stored in a variable in quotes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Let us have a path

```
C:\Program Files\TestFolder
```

this path i got programatically and stored in a varible dirpath(for example)
Now i have concatinated string

```
dirpath=getInstallationpath()+"\\ test.dll /codebase /tlb";
```

then dirpath is become

```
C:\Program Files\TestFolder\test.dll /codebase /tlb
```

But my problem is i have make the path enclosed in  double quotes

```
"C:\Program Files\TestFolder\test.dll"
```

Because when i directly pass the dirpath as commandline for regasm in a CreateProcess() then  it should accept for C:\Program only because of white spaces.so i tried lot of stunts like

```
dirpath="\ "+getInstallationPath()+" \test.dll /codebase /tlb "
```

like that but did not worked...

So please Hep me in this regard...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: How is this different from the problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177323/how-to-pass-the-directory-path-as-command-line-for-the-process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two issues with that line.  First of all, you need to escape the backslash preceding test.dll.  Secondly, wrapping the path in quotation marks requires that you also escape the quotation marks.

After these changes, it should look like this:

```
dirpath="\""+getInstallationPath()+"\\test.dll\" /codebase /tlb "
```

**Edit:**

Fixed the assignment per Martin's request.  Forgot a closing quotation mark for the first string!

Comment: It compiles under g++ with dirpath as a string.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you forgot the second \" after test.dll

Answer (score 2):

For building complex strings it is usually easier (and more effecient) to use a string stream.

```
// Note the character(") and the character(\)
// will need to be escaped when used inside a string
std::stringstream  stuff;
suff << "\"" 
     << getInstallationPath() << "\\test.dll" 
     << "\""
     << "/codebase /tlb";
                                                //
dirpath = stuff.str();
```